# Share page via Facebook app.

Tags: facebook, url

i want to share a URL to facebook but using the app, not the website. I have found the following list of links which open the app, however none of them seem to let me share a URL!

Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
{https://m.facebook.com}/pages/launchpoint/admin_invites/
{https://m.facebook.com}/pages/launchpoint/liked_pages/
{https://m.facebook.com}/pages/launchpoint/owned_pages/
{https://m.facebook.com}/pages/launchpoint/pending_invites/

fb-service://limit_friend_requests

fb://about
fb://account/recovery
fb://account_settings
fb://add_services
fb://ads/preferences/?tracking=%s
fb://ads_experience/?id=%s
fb://adsmanager/%s/insights/%s
fb://adsmanager/{account}/insights/{campaignGroup}
fb://adsmanager/image/select/%s
fb://adsmanager/image/select/{page}
fb://albums
fb://albums/%s
fb://albums_edit_flow
fb://ama?entryPoint=%s&targetURI=%s
fb://anniversary_video?campaign_id=%s
fb://anniversary_video?campaign_id={campaign_id}
fb://a-place-for/%s
fb://app_discovery_lite?appInviteId=%s&referrer=%s
fb://app_discovery_lite?packageName=%s&referrer=%s
fb://app_section/%s/%s
fb://appcenter
fb://appcenter/detail?app_id=%s
fb://appfeed
fb://appinvites/
fb://background_location/nux?source=%s&redirect_after_accept=%s&informational=%s
fb://background_location/nux?source=%s&redirect_after_accept=%s&nux_type=%s
fb://background_location/settings
fb://background_location/settings?theme=%s
fb://backstage/reply/
fb://backstage/stack/
fb://birthday_card/
fb://birthdays
fb://bookmarks
fb://bookmarks_section
fb://boost_event/?page_id=%s&graphql_story_id=%s&legacy_story_id=%s&promotion_target_id=%s&placement_extra=%s&referral=%s
fb://boost_post/?page_id=%s&graphql_story_id=%s&legacy_story_id=%s&referral=%s
fb://browser_extensions/commerce/?page_id=%s&extension=%s
fb://cardboard
fb://codegenerator
fb://collection/%s/%s/%s
fb://commerce/admin/products/%s/edit
fb://commerce/admin/products/add
fb://commerce/admin/shop/%s/add
fb://commerce/admin/shop/%s/edit
fb://commerce/collectionview/%s
fb://commerce/collectionview/ad/%s
fb://commerce/products/%s
fb://commerce/products/%s/edit
fb://commerce/products/<p$1>
fb://commerce/products/add
fb://commerce/shop/%s
fb://commerce_inventory?groupID=%s
fb://composer/?view={%s}&profile_type={%s -1}&target={%s -1}
fb://composer/topic_selector
fb://coverphoto
fb://cta_promotion?page_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s
fb://data_savings_mode_settings
fb://data_savings_mode_settings/?source=bar
fb://data_savings_mode_settings/?source=bookmarks
fb://data_savings_nux
fb://data_savings_quick_promotion
fb://data_savings_quick_promotion_dialog
fb://data_sensitivity_settings
fb://data_sensitivity_settings/?source=bookmarks
fb://dbl_loggedin_settings
fb://dialtone_info_screen
fb://donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&action_type=%2$s
fb://donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&post_id=%2$s
fb://donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&post_id=0
fb://donate/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
fb://donate?source=%1$s&fundraiser_campaign_id=%2$s
fb://donate_create
fb://donate_create/?fundraiser_charity_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
fb://donate_create/?source=%1$s
fb://donate_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s
fb://donate_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
fb://donate_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s&is_creator=%3$s
fb://donate_single_click_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s
fb://donate_single_click_invite/?fundraiser_campaign_id=%1$s&source=%2$s
fb://editor?entry_point=%s
fb://event/%s
fb://event/%s/extendedinvite
fb://event/%s/invite
fb://event/%s/invitegroup/%s
fb://event/%s/messagefriends
fb://event/%s/messagefriends/asgroup
fb://event_collection
fb://event_creation
fb://event_creation/
fb://event_creation/%s
fb://event_creation/{#%s}
fb://event_creation/categories
fb://event_creation/notification?story_cache_id=%s
fb://event_creation/prefill/%s
fb://event_discovery
fb://events
fb://events/{%s}/reaction
fb://events/section?section_name=%s
fb://events/section?section_name={%s}
fb://events_suggestion?cuttype={%s}
fb://faceweb/f?href=
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Ffriends%2Fcenter%2Ffriends%2F
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Fhelp%2Fwork
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Flegal%2FFB_Work_Terms
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Fnearby_info%2Fmanage_hidden_pages
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Fonavo/promotion/install
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Fpolicies
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Fprivacy
fb://faceweb/f?href=%2Fprivacy%2Ftouch%2Ftimeline_and_tagging
fb://faceweb/f?href=%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=%s&force_faceweb=true
fb://faceweb/f?href=/%s/legacy_contact
fb://faceweb/f?href=/%s/year/%d
fb://faceweb/f?href=/ads/manager
fb://faceweb/f?href=/commerce/contact-merchant/dialog/?product_item_id=%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=/coupons/info/?coupon_id=%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=/event/%s/madminpanel/pending
fb://faceweb/f?href=/follow/feedsources?source=bookmark
fb://faceweb/f?href=/groups
fb://faceweb/f?href=/instant_article/publisher_ad_about
fb://faceweb/f?href=/media/set/?set=ft.%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=/pages/create/?ref_type=android_timeline
fb://faceweb/f?href=/pages/create/?ref_type=page_more_menu
fb://faceweb/f?href=/pages/create/?ref_type=pages_nav_home
fb://faceweb/f?href=/pages/messaging/action/compose/?post_id=%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=/pages/place_claim/entry_redirect/?page_id=%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=/profile/intro/edit/about
fb://faceweb/f?href=/profile/intro/edit/links
fb://faceweb/f?href=/send_page_invite/?pageid=%s&reference=pages_nav_home
fb://faceweb/f?href=/timeline/friend_list_view/?profile_id=%s
fb://faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/onthisday/notification/settings/?source=permalink
fb://faceweb/f?href=https://m.facebook.com/onthisday/preferences/?source=permalink
fb://facewebmodal/f?href=%s
fb://fb_photos_picker
fb://fb_photos_picker/?campaign=%s
fb://feed
fb://feed_awesomizer
fb://feed_awesomizer/connections
fb://feed_awesomizer/following
fb://feed_awesomizer/see_first
fb://feed_awesomizer/unfollowed
fb://feed_settings
fb://feed_switcher?switcher_item_id={%s}
fb://findfriends
fb://findfriends/browser
fb://findfriends/learn_more
fb://findfriends?ci_flow=%s
fb://findfriends?ci_flow=%s&ccu_ref=%s&force_show_legal_screen=true
fb://findfriends?ci_flow=%s&force_show_legal_screen=true
fb://findfriends?ci_flow=CONTINUOUS_SYNC&ccu_ref=%s&force_show_legal_screen=true
fb://findfriends?ci_flow=CONTINUOUS_SYNC&force_show_legal_screen=true
fb://free_facebook_settings
fb://free_fb_invite
fb://friending/suggestion/%s/%s
fb://friending_possibilities?location=%s
fb://friendlist/%s
fb://friends/
fb://friends/accept/notifications
fb://friends/center
fb://friends/center?fc_tab=%s
fb://friends/center?source_ref=%s
fb://friends/center?source_ref=%s&fc_tab=%s
fb://friends/center?source_ref=%s&fc_tab=requests&user_id=%s&name=%s&profile_pic=%s
fb://friends/immersivepymk
fb://friends/requests/
fb://friends/requests_tab
fb://friendship
fb://friendship/%s/%s
fb://friendsnearby/profile?fbid=%s&source=%s
fb://friendsnearby?source=%s
fb://friendsnearby_invite?selected=%s&excluded=%s
fb://getgames
fb://gift/receive?gid=%s
fb://goodfriends/camera
fb://goodfriends/nux_flow
fb://goodfriends/select_audience
fb://graphsearch
fb://graphsearch/query?q=%s&display_style=%s&title=%s
fb://group/%s
fb://group/%s/yourposts
fb://group/{%s}/permalink/{%s}/comment/{%s}
fb://groups/addtogroups/%s?profile_name=%s
fb://groups/create
fb://groups/create?ref=%s
fb://groups/createtab
fb://groups/discover
fb://groups/discover/categories
fb://groups/discover/category?id={%s}
fb://groups/discover/tag?id=%s
fb://groups/discover/tag?id={%s}
fb://groups/events/{%s}
fb://groups/gridtab
fb://groups/members/{%s}
fb://groups/photos/{%s}
fb://groups/settings/{%s}
fb://groups/suggestions?source=%s
fb://groups/suggestions?source={%s}
fb://groups_hub_search
fb://groups_tab
fb://gv/editor/card?campaign_id=%s&campaign_type=%s&direct_source=%s
fb://gv/share?campaign_id=%s&campaign_type=%s&source=%s&direct_source=%s&share_preview=%s&share_autofill=%s&share_placeholder=%s
fb://hashtag/%s?name=%s&id=%s
fb://help
fb://id_backed_privacy_checkup/checkup_id=%s
fb://id_backed_privacy_checkup_react/?checkup_id=%s
fb://instant_articles
fb://instant_shopping_catalog/?catalog_id={%s -1}&catalog_view={%s -1}&product_id={%s -1}&product_view={%s -1}
fb://instant_shopping_catalog/?catalog_id={%s}
fb://iorg/basicServices
fb://jobApplication
fb://language_switch
fb://languages/?locale=%s
fb://lead_gen/?lead_gen_data_id={%s -1}&ad_id={%s -1}
fb://leadgen/?lead_gen_data_id={%s -1}&ad_id={%s -1}
fb://link_fb_invite
fb://live_sport_event/%s/%s
fb://local_awareness_promotion/?page_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s
fb://localsell_home/?tabIndex=%s&referralSurface=%s
fb://location_settings
fb://loginapprovalspush
fb://look_now
fb://maps
fb://marketplace_activity?id=%s
fb://marketplace_category_menu
fb://marketplace_category_search
fb://marketplace_composer/?assetIDs=%s
fb://marketplace_editcomposer/?storyID=%s&referralSurface=%s
fb://marketplace_forsalegroupshome
fb://marketplace_forsalegroupshome_story
fb://marketplace_home
fb://marketplace_initial_message
fb://marketplace_location
fb://marketplace_message
fb://marketplace_message/?threadID=%s
fb://marketplace_message/?threadID=%s&assetIDs=%s
fb://marketplace_message/?threadID=%s&referralSurface=%s
fb://marketplace_notifications
fb://marketplace_product_details
fb://marketplace_product_details?id=%s&referralSurface=%s
fb://marketplace_product_details_from_post_id/?post_id=%s
fb://marketplace_product_message_threads
fb://marketplace_product_message_threads/?productTitle=%s&productID=%s&referralSurface=%s
fb://marketplace_profile?id=%s
fb://marketplace_saved
fb://marketplace_saved_search_results
fb://marketplace_search
fb://marketplace_your_items
fb://marketplacesearch
fb://mediaset/brpi.%s
fb://mediaset/brpo.%s
fb://mediaset/oa.%s
fb://mediaset/pb.%s
fb://menu_management?page_id=%s
fb://messaging
fb://messaging/
fb://messaging/%s
fb://messaging/compose/
fb://messaging/compose/%s
fb://messaging/compose/new
fb://messaging/compose/new/group
fb://messaging/groupthreadfbid/
fb://messaging/groupthreadfbid/%s
fb://messaging/thread/thread?id=
fb://messaging/thread/thread?id=%s
fb://messaging_tab
fb://moments/upsell
fb://multi_post_story/%s
fb://multi_post_story/{%s}
fb://multi_post_story/{%s}?name={%s}
fb://native_album/%s
fb://native_article?article={%s}
fb://native_article?article={%s}&canonical={%s}
fb://native_article?article={%s}&canonical={%s}&saved={%s}
fb://native_document/?id={%s -1}
fb://native_note/{%s}
fb://native_post/%s?fallback_url=%s
fb://native_post/%s?story_cache_id=%s
fb://nativename
fb://nearby
fb://nearby/?wifi=1
fb://nearby/search
fb://nearby/subcategory
fb://nearbyInfoSettings
fb://newContactPoint
fb://note/%s
fb://notification_settings
fb://notification_settings_alerts
fb://notifications
fb://notifications_friending
fb://notifications_tab
fb://now/
fb://nt/shell
fb://nux/profile_picture?external_photo_source=%s
fb://offers/barcode_fullscreen/?title=%s&extra_image_url=%s
fb://offers/detail/?coupon_id=%s
fb://offers/detail/?offer_claim_id=%s
fb://offers/detail/?offer_id=%s&share_id=%s&notif_trigger=%s&notif_medium=%s&rule=%s
fb://offers/detail/?offer_id=%s&share_id=%s&redirect=%s
fb://offers/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&notif_trigger=%s&notif_medium=%s&rule=%s
fb://offers/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&redirect=%s
fb://offers/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&redirect=%s&claim_type=%s
fb://offers/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&redirect=%s&offer_should_claim=%s
fb://offers/wallet
fb://offersite/detail/?offer_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s
fb://offersite/detail/?offer_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&notif_trigger=%s&notif_medium=%s&rule=%s
fb://offersite/detail/?offer_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&offer_code=%s
fb://offersite/detail/?offer_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&offer_code=%s&notif_trigger=%s&notif_medium=%s&rule=%s
fb://offersite/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&claim_type=%s
fb://offersite/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s
fb://offersite/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&notif_trigger=%s&notif_medium=%s&rule=%s
fb://offersite/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&offer_code=%s
fb://offersite/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&offer_code=%s&claim_type=%s
fb://offersite/detail/view/?offer_view_id=%s&share_id=%s&site_uri=%s&title=%s&offer_code=%s&notif_trigger=%s&notif_medium=%s&rule=%s
fb://online
fb://onthisday?source=%s
fb://onthisday?source=%s&campaign_id=%s&story_id=%s
fb://page/%s
fb://page/%s/admin_feed
fb://page/%s/admin_stories
fb://page/%s/album_list
fb://page/%s/call_to_action
fb://page/%s/child_locations
fb://page/%s/contactinbox
fb://page/%s/events_list
fb://page/%s/info
fb://page/%s/invite_friends_to_like_page
fb://page/%s/offers
fb://page/%s/pendingedits
fb://page/%s/reaction
fb://page/%s/recommendations
fb://page/%s/residence
fb://page/%s/scheduled_posts
fb://page/%s/service/%s
fb://page/%s/services_list
fb://page/%s/suggestedit?entry_point=%s
fb://page/%s/timeline
fb://page/%s/videohub
fb://page/%s/videolist?page_id=%s&source=%s
fb://page/%s/vistor_posts
fb://page/{%s}/tab/{%s}
fb://page/{%s}/videohub
fb://page/{%s}/videolist?page_id={%s}&source={%s}
fb://page/create_new_page
fb://page/messages/%s
fb://page/videolist?page_id=%s&source=%s
fb://page/videolist?page_id={%s}&source={%s}
fb://page/view_album/%s
fb://page_like_promotion/?page_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s
fb://page_link_menu_management?page_id=%s
fb://pages
fb://pages/?category=%s
fb://pages/comments/%s
fb://pages/launchpoint
fb://pages/messaging/private_reply/dialog/%s/%s
fb://payment_settings
fb://payments/sampleflows
fb://photo/%s
fb://photo/%s/?set=%s
fb://photo_checkup/?source=%s&checkup_type=%s
fb://photo_menu/?page_id=%s
fb://photo_menu/add/?page_id=%s
fb://photosbycategory/?page_id=%s
fb://pivhelp
fb://place/creation
fb://placefeed?placeid=%s&surface=%s
fb://placefeed?placeid=%s&surface=%s&placename=%s
fb://placefeed?placeid=%s&surface=%s&placename=%s&wildcard=%s
fb://placelist_map
fb://platform_first_party
fb://pokes
fb://policies
fb://post/%s
fb://privacy_checkup/?source=%s
fb://privacy_review_lightweight/?checkup_type=%s
fb://profile
fb://profile/%s
fb://profile/%s/activitylog
fb://profile/%s/activitylog_search
fb://profile/%s/activitylog_search/%s
fb://profile/%s/friends/%s
fb://profile/%s/friends/%s?source_ref=%s
fb://profile/%s/info/expanded
fb://profile/%s/info/inner
fb://profile/%s?skip_popup=true
fb://profile/?id={profileId}&profile_type=person&intro_card=edit_featured_photos
fb://profile/info_request/%s/%s
fb://profile/section_stories/%d/%d
fb://profile/video/pick_thumbnail
fb://profile?frame_id={%s}&entry_point={%s}
fb://profile_qr?source=%s
fb://profileInfoUpdate?is_minor_user={!%s false}
fb://profilepictureupload
fb://profileshare/immersive
fb://promote_product/?page_id=%s&promotion_target_id=%s&referral=%s
fb://prompt/{%s}invite
fb://qp/%s?data=%s&fallback_url=%s
fb://qp/%s?fallback_url=%s
fb://qrcodelogin/?info={%s}
fb://reaction/session/%s/chrome
fb://reaction-demo
fb://redspace
fb://redspace/friends/overflow
fb://redspace/visitors
fb://registration
fb://reviews/?page_id=%s
fb://reviews/?review_id=%s
fb://reviews/?user_id=%s
fb://safetycheck?crisisID=%s
fb://salegroups
fb://samplernintegration
fb://saved
fb://saved/?section_name=%s&referer=%s
fb://saved/?section_name={%s}&referer={%s}
fb://search_typeahead_results/?module=MarketplaceSearch
fb://settings
fb://sg/fundraiser/?source=%1$s&fundraiser_campaign_id=%2$s
fb://shops
fb://social_search_conversion?post_id=%s&entry_point=%s&funnel_logging_tags=%s
fb://sports/%s
fb://sports_dashboard
fb://sports_league/%s
fb://stack/
fb://stack_camera/
fb://stack_import/
fb://stack_story/{id}
fb://store_locator/?north=%s&west=%s&south=%s&east=%s&ad_id=%s&page_set_id=%s&parent_page_id=%s
fb://story/%s/%s
fb://storygallerysurvey
fb://structured_menu/?page_id=%s
fb://topic_feeds_customization
fb://trust/afro/?hideable_token=%s&story_graphql_token=%s&initial_action=%s&story_location=%s&tracking=%s
fb://trust/afro/?reportable_ent_graphql_id=%s&initial_action=%s&story_location=%s
fb://trust/afro/?reportable_ent_token=%s&initial_action=%s&story_location=%s
fb://video/%s?source_url=%s
fb://video/?href={href}
fb://video/?id={%s}
fb://video/{%s}?source_url={href}
fb://video_home
fb://video_home/guide
fb://video_notification/%s
fb://videochannel?id=%s
fb://website_promotion/?page_id=%s&source=%s&referral=%s&restore_saved_settings=%s
fb://webview/?url={%s}
fb://work_groups_tab
fb://zero_dialog
```